# How to define a function of parameters of a DSolve output?

Tags: differential-equations, functions

If I have some ODE that has some parameters, say $a$ and $k$, how would I define a function of those parameters of the solution `DSolve`.

For example consider the following code

```
sol = DSolve[{U'[t] == -k^2*I*a*U[t], U[0] == k}, U, t]

U[k_, t_, a_] := U[t] /. sol
```

the above ODE has two parameters, $a$ and $k$, if I want to define a function $U(k,t,a)$ how would I do that?

My above attempt does not work as it does not treat $a$ and $k$ as variables, only $t$, is there a way to define such a function?

Comment: `(Clear[U]; U[k_, t_, a_] = DSolveValue[{U'[t] == -k^2*I*a*U[t], U[0] == k}, U[t], t]);`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you want to do is, with `=` instead of `:=`,

```
Clear[sol, U];
sol = DSolve[{U'[t] == -k^2 I a U[t], U[0] == k}, U, t];
U[k_, t_, a_] = U[t] /. First[sol];
```

```
U[1, 1, 1]  (* gives E^(-I) *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve with the parameters directly:

```
sol = DSolve[{D[U[t, k, a], t] == -k^2*I*a*U[t, k, a], 
   U[0, k, a] == k}, U, {t, k, a}]

(*  {{U -> Function[{t, k, a}, E^(-I a k^2 t) k]}}  *)
```

If you want a function, then I would avoid naming the function the same name as the variable. If you make it a function, you can't use it as a variable. But you can do it if you want to. Whether you want to call it `UFN` as below or just `U`, you can define it with `DSolveValue`:

```
UFN = DSolveValue[{D[U[t, k, a], t] == -k^2*I*a*U[t, k, a], 
   U[0, k, a] == k}, U, {t, k, a}]

(*  Function[{t, k, a}, E^(-I a k^2 t) k]  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

An other way with DSolve is

```
Usol[a_, k_] = 
 U /. Flatten@DSolve[{U'[t] == -k^2*I*a*U[t], U[0] == k}, U, t]

(*   Function[{t}, E^(-I a k^2 t) k]   *)

{U'[t] == -k^2*I*a*U[t], U[0] == k} /. U -> Usol[a, k] // Simplify

(*   {True, True}   *)
```

How to use. Plot the real part of the second derivative

```
Plot[Re[Usol[2, 3]''[t]], {t, 0, 5}]
```